# Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception thrown during the rendering of a template

Tags: php, symfony

I have URL error:

```
    link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Latest Jobs" 
href="{{ url('job', {'_format': 'atom'}) }}" />
```

Routing.yml file:

```
job_job:
    resource: "@JobBundle/Resources/config/routing/job.yml"
    prefix:   /job

job_homepage:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: JobBundle:Default:index }
```

This what my job.yml contains -

(I use in path "job_homepage" , in url I use "job" , but when I'm trying to run show action or edit action it work correctly)

```
job_index:
path:     /
defaults: { _controller: "JobBundle:Job:index" }
methods:  GET

job_show:
path:     /{id}/show
defaults: { _controller: "JobBundle:Job:show" }
methods:  GET

job_new:
path:     /new
defaults: { _controller: "JobBundle:Job:new" }
methods:  [GET, POST]

job_edit:
path:     /{id}/edit
defaults: { _controller: "JobBundle:Job:edit" }
methods:  [GET, POST]

job_delete:
path:     /{id}/delete
defaults: { _controller: "JobBundle:Job:delete" }
methods:  DELETE
```

I use `http://127.0.0.1:8000/job/` to run my project

Comment: Do you have registered route called just `job`? Could you paste error message?

Comment: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "job" as such route does not exist.").

Comment: please add more details to your question

Comment: You are trying to load routes correct? If so, I'm not sure if you can use `job_job` in the routing.yml file. All examples I see show `app:`. Also, what does the file "/Resources/config/routing/job.yml" contain? Can you edit your post and show that?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have a route for `job` in your routing file.

Should be something like:

```
link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Latest Jobs" href="{{ url('job_homepage', {'_format': 'atom'}) }}" />
```

Or if you have different named routes in "@JobBundle/Resources/config/routing/job.yml" use one of those. But the error is pretty clear, you dont have a route named `job`

Comment: yes i have different route and when i try to run it it works correctly but the route job doesn't work :/